# Show that there exists $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t $a^2 \equiv -2 \pmod p$.

Tags: number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime such that $p \equiv 1, 3 \pmod 8 $.
(a) Show that there exists $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t $a^2 \equiv -2 \pmod p$.

Could someone provide a hint?

Comment: Quadratic reciprocity.

Comment: I tried using $(2/p) = ±1 if p =1,3 \pmod 8$ but didn't get too far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the *law of quadratic reciprocity*:
$$\def\leg#1#2{\left(\dfrac{#1}{#2}\right)}\leg{-2}p=\leg{-1}p\leg2p$$
Now $\leg{-1}p=\begin{cases}1&\text{if}\enspace p\equiv 1\mod 4,\\-1& \text{if} \enspace p\equiv 3\mod 4
\end{cases}\quad $
and 
 $\quad\leg{2}p=\begin{cases}1&\text{if}\enspace p\equiv 1, 7\mod 8\\-1& \text{if} \enspace p\equiv 3,5\mod 8
\end{cases}\quad $

Combining the different possible situations gives the answer.

Comment: But how I can this be written as $a^2 \equiv -2 \pmod p$

Comment: If you want to know if this is possible, the law of quadratic reciprocity gives the answer. If you want the value of $a$, that depends on $p$.

Comment: @Tony Look https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_quadratic_reciprocity. Use the Lemma in Eisenstein's proof.

Comment: You cannot use the lemma since 1 is not a prime

Comment: @Tony: I use the two supplementary laws, not the general law. These supplementary laws rest  on [Gauß's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_%28number_theory%29).

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

For any $a \in \mathbb{Z}$, $$a \equiv 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 \pmod 8$$
$$a^2 \equiv 0,1,4 \pmod 8$$

Now use the condition that $p \equiv 1,3 \pmod 8$

Comment: Still don't see what to do.

Comment: $a^2$ is either of the form $8k$ or $8k+1$ or $8k+4$ and $p$ can be of the form $8m+1$ or $8m+3$. Now do you get the hint? Your job is to show that there exists at least one M such that $a^2+2=Mp$.

Comment: I see what you are trying to say, but wouldn't that have many cases to consider. If $a^2$ is of the form $8k$ then $a^2+2=8k+2=2(8m+1)?$, $a^2$ is of the form $8k+1$ then $a^2+2=8k+3$ and $a^2$ is of the form $8k+4$ then $a^2+2=8k+6=2(8m+3)?$