# There exists $a$ s.t the 2 equations both have integer solutions.

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-residues

> For each prime $p>5$, prove that there always exists an integer $a$
> s.t the two following equations $$x^2+py+a=0\quad\text{and}\quad
> x^2+py+a+2=0$$ both have integer solutions.

Here are my thoughts for this problem:
$x^2+py+a=0\iff x^2+a\equiv 0\pmod{p}$ and $m^2+pn+a+2=0\iff m^2+a+2\equiv 0\pmod{p}.$
So if there exists an integer $a$ s.t $\left(\dfrac{-a}{p}\right)=\left(\dfrac{-a-2}{p}\right)=1$ then we finish.
But I don't know whether such $a$ exists. Could someone help me or have another way to deal with this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: hmmm. for prime 5, residues 4 and 6. For that matter, for $p=3$  take $-a = 3,$  $-a-2 = 1$   There is something wrong with the problem as stated. "Integer solutions"  allow for $ 0 \pmod p.$   Perhaps they have in mind a pigeonhole argument that works for $p \geq 7$

Comment: so: where did you get the problem?

Comment: Sorry if I didn't understand correctly, but all we need to show is that $\frac{-a}{p}-\frac{-a-2}{p}=0$ !?!

Comment: There is no solution @AlexNguyen. Eventually, you get $2/p=0$, which has no solutions.

Comment: @LucienJaccon FYI, the notation such as $\left(\frac{-a}{p}\right)$ used here is the [Legendre symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol) rather than just being brackets around a fraction. Note that mathematics sometimes reuses symbols for different purposes, so their meaning in those cases either needs to be explicitly stated or be inferred based on context.

Answer (score 2):

You have made a good start on a valid approach. To prove an integer $a$ always exists, consider several special cases. For $a = -1$, since $\left(\frac{-a}{p}\right) = \left(\frac{1}{p}\right) = 1$ for all primes, check when $\left(\frac{-a-2}{p}\right) = \left(\frac{-1}{p}\right) = 1$. By [$q = \pm 1$ and the first supplement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity#q_=_%C2%B11_and_the_first_supplement), we have that $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ works.

Thus, we have only $p \equiv 3\pmod{4}$ left, which can be handled with $p \equiv 3\pmod{8}$ and $p \equiv 7\pmod{8}$ separately. With $a = 0$ satisfying the first [Legendre symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol), we need $\left(\frac{-a-2}{p}\right) = \left(\frac{-2}{p}\right) = 1$. By [$q = \pm 2$ and the second supplement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity#q_=_%C2%B12_and_the_second_supplement) (also in [Show that there exists $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t $a^2 \equiv -2 \pmod p$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1684303/602049)), we have $p \equiv 1, 3\pmod{8}$, so this covers the $p \equiv 3\pmod{8}$ case. With $a = -4$ satisfying the first value, then for $\left(\frac{-a-2}{p}\right) = \left(\frac{2}{p}\right) = 1$, by [$q = \pm 2$ and the second supplement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity#q_=_%C2%B12_and_the_second_supplement) again, we have $p \equiv 1, 7\pmod{8}$, so this covers the remaining $p \equiv 7\pmod{8}$ case.

Note the table in [Law of quadratic reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue#Law_of_quadratic_reciprocity) also has these results. In addition, you could use quadratic reciprocity or other means to determine other sets of $a$ values which cover all of the odd primes $p$.

Answer (score 1):

There is a combinatorial way of doing this, for those who know basic graph theory, that uses far less number theory as well. Indeed, we need just the following:

**Lemma 1:** *Let $C$ be a cycle and let $A$ be a subset of the vertices of $C$ s.t. $A$ is more than half the vertices of $C$. Then at least two vertices in $A$ are adjacent in $C$.*

To see Lemma 1, start by drawing say a cycle $C$ on $5$ vertices and observing that, if $A$ be any subset of $3$ vertices, then at least two vertices in $A$ have to be adjacent to each other in $C$. Then try for $C$ w $7$ vertices and $A$ with $4$ vertices. $\surd$

Let $C$ be the graph on the elements of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ where two integers $i$ and $j$ are adjacent if $i-j$ is in $\{-2,2\}$, or equivalently, either $j=i+2$ or $i=j+2$. Then note that  $C$ is a cycle on the $p$ vertices of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, because $\gcd(p,2)$ is $1$.

Next, let $A$ be the elements $a$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ such that $-a$ is a square residue.

Then to prove this result, note that it suffices to show that there are two elements in $A$ adjacent to each other in $C$. However, $|A| = \frac{p+1}{2}$ i.e., larger than half the vertices in $C$ which is a cycle. [You did learn that half of the elements in $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^×$ plus $\{0\}$ form the set of square residues, right?]  So two vertices in $A$ have to be adjacent to each other in $C$, by Lemma 1. And so that gives the desired result. ■

---

Can you generalize? What if you wanted to show that there is an $a \in \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ such that both $a$ and $a+3$ are square residues? What about the existence of an $a\in \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ such that both $a$ and $a+c$ are both square residues, for all $c$ s.t. $\gcd(p,c)=1$?

Comment: This is extremely cool (for me)! Had you seen such proofs before, or did you conjure it up on the spot?

Comment: Thanks D.S. this came from studying Cayley graphs along with basic group theory and number theory.